# Might in a sentence

Tags: meaning

> It might be because your shoes are too small.

Does this imply: "Your shoes might be too small, which might be why."

Or: "Your shoes are too small, which might be why."

Might means "possible", so I translated it to:

> It's possible it is because your shoes are too small.

> Your shoes are possibly too small, which is possibly the reason.

> Your shoes are too small, which is possibly the reason.

Comment: It is not stated that the shoes definitely are too small, only that they might be. The reason (e.g. for your sore feet) could be that your shoes are too small, or your shoes might not be too small, and the reason might be something else.

Comment: Without context it's impossible to tell which is meant.